# Print subset of matrix

Tags: sas, sas-iml

I'm trying to create a code to run a simple perceptron in SAS base.
I'd like to print in each iteration (or store in a table) the result and the target, but I get an error when I try to print y[i,]:

```
proc iml; 
use percept; read all var{x1 X2} into X; 
            read all var{Y} into Y; 

W={0,0}; b=0; k=0; L=nrow(X); eta=.8; o=0;
print w b k L eta; 

do step = 1 to 6;   
mistakes=0; 
    do i=1 to L; 
    o=(X[i, ]*W + b);
         if Y[i, ]*o <= 0 then do;
            W = W + eta*(Y[i, ]-o)*X[i,]`; 
            b = b + eta*(Y[i, ]-o)*1; 
            k=k+1; mistakes=mistakes+1; 
            print o  Y[i, ] W b k mistakes; 
          end; 
    end; 
end;
```

I get the error:

> Syntax error, expecting one of the following: C, COLNAME, F, FORMAT,
>   L, LABEL, R,
>                 ROWNAME, ], |). The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.

Do I have any other form to print the target?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think I solve it, I created a variable in each loop t=Y[i,] and then print t instead of Y[i,]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation on PRINT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/59656/HTML/default/viewer.htm#langref_sect205.htm), you need to do it like this:

```
print(Y[i,])
```

This is because they overload the `[ ]` to indicate formatting, rownames/colnames, etc., which is rather silly (but presumably to imitate some other language?).  So you just need to wrap `(Y[i,])` like so.

Here's a silly example.

```
proc iml;
 use sashelp.class;
  read all var{name,sex} into class;
  read all var{height,weight,age} into classN;

 y = mean(classN[,2]);
 print class;
 print (class[1:2,]);
 print y (class[1:2,]);
quit;
```

Comment: And you can use the LABEL= option or COLNAME= option to help identify those temporary expressions:
 print y[Label="Mean"] 
       (class[1:2,])[Colname={"Name" "Sex"}];